# Convert days from gmdate() into hours?

Tags: php, date

How may I turn days from the `gmdate();` into hours?

```
gmdate("d H:i:s", '115932'); // 02 08:12:12
```

What I want to return is 56:12:12

```
gmdate("H:i:s", '115932'); // 08:12:12
```

EDIT: To clarify, I just want to convert a numeric string into the H:i:s format.

Comment: `gmdate` is to be used to work with dates, not with intervals.

Comment: Where does 56 come from?

Comment: OP it would be nice if you could chime in and tell us what you are really after.

Comment: Take a string that is a number in seconds, and convert it to the H:i:s format. You were spot on.

Comment: @duck just to be sure 115932 seconds is 32:12:12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert days `d` to hours, just multiply by by 24. Then add hours `H`.

Try this,

```
$date = '115932';

$minsec = gmdate("i:s", $date); 
$hours = gmdate("d", $date)*24 + gmdate("H", $date);

$time = $hours . ':' . $minsec; // 56:12:12
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/pC07gKkR)

Comment: This will not work if the daylight saving time changes in that interval. Meaning it is bogus during two months per year.

Comment: @hek2mgl I believe you, and will delete my answer if it's wrong, but can you explain a little more? My answer simply converts days to hours. How would daylight savings cause a bug?

Comment: the number of seconds doesn't match the end time... try `$date = 100` you'll get 24:01:40 because as @hek2mgl was trying to say gmdate is for parsing dates not intervals... So I'm not sure why this is the correct answer. Plus it doesn't work that well with `$date > 31 days`

Comment: with duration = 3000 seconds you output will be: 24:50:00

Answer (score 2):

Extract the hours, minutes and seconds, like this:

```
$time = 115932;
$mins = $time % 3600;
$secs = $mins % 60;
$hours = ($time - $mins) / 3600;
$mins = ($mins - $secs) / 60;
echo $hours . ':' . (($mins < 10 ) ? '0' : '') . $mins . ':'  . (($secs < 10 ) ? '0' : '') . $secs;
// Or like this
vprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d',$hours,$mins,$secs);
```

Comment: What if there is a daylight saving time change?

Comment: Does it apply to time intervals?

Comment: Yes, because it would be 1 hour more or less then.

Comment: I skipped the whole date parsing... i asume he just wants to convert seconds into a more readable format.

Comment: No, OP wants the time in hours, minutes, seconds from the start of the month.

Comment: @hek2mgl: daylight saving time has nothing to do with intervals, +1d

Comment: @hek2mgl: "from the start of the month" --- uhm, why do you think so?

Comment: @zerkms It has indeed something to do with. Isn't this obvious?

Comment: @zerkms Because the formatter `d` in `gmdate()` contains the number of days from the start of the month

Comment: @hek2mgl: obvious?? I see that OP needs to format an interval specified into hours:minutes:seconds.

Comment: @hek2mgl: in this case `d` is just number of days in a given interval in seconds. OP just misused the `gmdate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58565/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-zerkms).