# How to use gmdate() to display more than 24 hours, but not days

Tags: php, datetime

I want to display a time like this

```
80:00:00
```

Hours:Minutes:Seconds

When I use this

```
gmdate("H:i:s", $time)
```

It displays

```
08:00:00
```

gmdate() has hours display 0 once it reaches 24, start counting up to 24 again.

I have tried this

```
$minsec = gmdate("i:s", $time);
$hours = gmdate("d", $time)*24 + gmdate("H", $time);
echo $hours.':'.$minsec;
```

But this displays.

```
32:00:00
```

I understand from elsewhere on stackoverflow this might be because of daylight savings time. See here.

[Convert days from gmdate() into hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102710/convert-days-from-gmdate-into-hours)

I have not found any good solutions. What is a consistent, function solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,  works for me:

```
$minsec = gmdate("i:s", $time);    
$hours = (gmdate("d", $time)-1)*24 + gmdate("H", $time);    
echo $hours.':'.$minsec;
```

The -1 is important because the day is one when the $ time = 1 second.
I do not know why, it must be because  always have one day.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do, and this works for me:

```
<?php
$hour = gmdate("H", time());
if($hour < 10) {
echo gmdate("0H:i:s", time()); // you can just add a 0 in front of the hour if it is less than 10
}
else {
echo gmdate("H:i:s", time());
}
?>
```

hope this helps. if not comment and tell me if this isn't what you want

Comment: No, that's not my issue. If it was, a lowercase h could give me the  0 in front. I want to be able to display 25 hours instead of a day and 1 hour.

Comment: couldn't you just do what you shared in the link above?

Comment: It doesn't return the correct time because daylight savings time screws it up